# Ubuntu 18.04 not working with Panda Wireless PAU09 on USB 3.0

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, usb, ralink

Recently received a Panda Wireless PAU09. It works fine on any of the computer's USB 2.0 ports, but not USB 3.0 ports. USB 3.0 ports are functional, as they can connect to other USB devices.

`lsusb` shows the device in the list:

```
Bus 008 Device 000: ID 148f:5572 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT5572 Wireless Adapter
```

However, `lshw -C network` shows only the ethernet interface.

The device works fine on a USB 3.0 port on Windows 10.